# Borrar varios registros getContentResolver DELETE

Tags: android

Este codigo elimina registros de llamadas solo con un parametro y es funcional.

```
uri = Uri.parse("content://call_log/calls");
String seleccion= CallLog.Calls.NUMBER + " LIKE ?";
String[] mSelectionArgs = {"1111111111"};
int mRowsDeleted = 0;
mRowsDeleted = getContentResolver().delete(
           uri,
           seleccion,
           mSelectionArgs);

xTxtCampo.setText("Borrados: " + mRowsDeleted);
```

Esto elimina todos los registros de llamadas donde el numero sea igual a 11111111, ahora quiero usar dos parametros es decir borrar todas las llamadas que sean iguales a 111111111 o 222222222